# Jquery random positioning of elements

Tags: jquery, html, random, position

I am trying to make the text randomly positioned on the screen. How do I do that?

I am using Textillate

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mub2gw59/1/)

```
<h1 class="tlt1">Go </h1>
```

Comment: use `<>` for demo.

Comment: I am trying those multiple <h1> elements appear at random positions on the screen. I am using Textillate.js for fadeIn and Outs and animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this either by `position:fixed` OR `position:absolute`.

```
$('.tlt').each(function(){
        $(this).css({"left": Math.random() * window.outerWidth , "top": Math.random() * window.outerHeight}).textillate();
});
```

OR

```
$('h1').each(function(){
        $(this).css({"left": Math.random() * window.outerWidth , "top": Math.random() * window.outerHeight}).textillate();
});
```

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mub2gw59/16/)

Answer (score 0):

You should set your CSS for your h1 tags to `position:fixed`. Then in your javascript for each h1 your generate set its `left` property to `Math.random() * window.outerWidth` and its `top` property to `Math.random() * window.outerHeight`.